# How do I fix BAD betta fin tearing?

Tags: fish, betta, filters, heaters

[image]
I’ve had my betta for a month now and hes been PERFECT!! I just looked at him now and saw that his tail is SHREDDED!! I realized that he had been glaring at the filter in the back and KNEW that he’d been at the back by the filter ALL NIGHT!! I ALWAYS check to make sure he’s fine DAILY! His tail was BEAUTIFUL last night when I fed him, today SHREDDED! I’ve covered the area of the filter where he was flaring to prevent further damage, but now I don’t know what I should do! I KNKW it’s not fin rot, it’s from the flow of the filter because he was by it all night long and flaring, so PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: Don't panic the same thing happened to me. My boy healed, he just needed time. Add some stress coat to your water, the Aloe vera is meant to aid healing

Comment: In addition to other answers, note that bettas like very low water movement. You might want to put your filter on the low setting. Or raise the water level so instead of a waterfall from the filter, the water would be directly dumped in the tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the pet store and ask for some aquarium salt and ask for a liquid in a little bottle or little plastic fish called Revive. Put around a pinch of salt per 10 gallon tank and 5/10 drops for the revive. Don’t panic your baby will be fine! Good idea to cover up the pump or filter he was by give him about 10 to 14 days and you should start noticing a change in him. He will start flaring out again and if you put a mirror up and he gets defensive then he is still strong and he just needs a lot of love and remember they love lots of soft reeds and plants as they come from rice fields and they like longer not higher tanks! Good luck with your baby .

Answer (score 3):

Double check that decor is all smooth. Some of that also looks like it could be fin biting.

Healing should be easy, just keep an eye out for rot (blackening around the edges of the wounds). Within a week new growth should begin with clear fins starting to fill back in. It should color up as normal with time.

All you need to do is keep the water as clean as possible, maybe do a few more water changes than normal while he heals. I've heard betta-fix is good for helping keep the wounds clean too (do not use plain mela-fix, bettas are sensitive to the full dosage).